# Change Time Unit with Kernprof

Tags: python, profiling, line-profiler

I've started looking for bottlenecks in Python using `line_profiler`. Right now, I am doing that by running

```
kernprof -l -v myFile.py
```

However, the unit of time seems to be at `1e-6`, which lead to output results such as `132329040`. How can I increase the time interval to make the output more readable for larger time deltas?

Comment: The time unit seems to be set in the timer.c code so unless changing that you could divide by 1000000

Comment: If the reason you are doing this is to find "bottlenecks" (as opposed to measuring for the sake of measuring), [*there's a completely different way to do it.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771) Measurements of time are completely beside the point.

Answer (score 9):

That is a feature so far only present via Jupyter line magic, as discussed [here](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/issues/136). It can be accessed via the "-u" flag, followed by the timer unit, in seconds. This is a sample usage:

```
def m():
  return [0]*10**8

%lprun -u 1e-3 -f m m()
```

Which displays the output with timer unit in milliseconds:

```
Out:
Timer unit: 0.001 s

Total time: 0.363548 s
File: 
Function: m at line 1

Line # Hits Time Per Hit % Time Line Contents
==============================================================
1 def m():
2 1 363.5 363.5 100.0 return [0]*10**8
```

As documented in this [PR](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/pull/98).

Comment: This works on normal version now.

Answer (score 6):

I find the solution by reading LineProfiler source code.
you can use the following parameter "output_unit"  to change the time unit.

```
profiler.print_stats(output_unit=1e-03)
```

output_unit=1e-03, the console will output "Timer unit: 0.001 s"
output_unit=1, the console will output "Timer unit: 1 s"

Answer (score 1):

In show_func function; around line num 202:

```
if output_unit is None:
    output_unit = unit
```

Change it to:

```
if output_unit is None:
    output_unit = unit*1000000
```

Secondly, in the function show_text; around line num 254:

```
if output_unit is not None:
    stream.write('Timer unit: %g s\n\n' % output_unit)
else:
    stream.write('Timer unit: %g s\n\n' % unit)
```

Change it to:

```
if output_unit is not None:
    stream.write('Timer unit: %g s\n\n' % output_unit)
else:
    stream.write('Timer unit: %g s\n\n' % (unit*1000000))
```

Use the same factor in both places.

I have made the above changes as I use line commands to run line_profiler and not ipython/jupyter.

The output file looks like following. The time units are so much more readable!

```
executed
Wrote profile results to test.py.lprof
Timer unit: 0.1 s

Total time: 1.00024 s
File: test.py
Function: testfunc at line 5

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     5                                           @profile
     6                                           def testfunc():
     7         1         10.0     10.0    100.0      time.sleep(1)
     8         1          0.0      0.0      0.0      print('executed')
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@mbv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12870750/mbv) above, this is now available with latest `line_profiler`, as of [PR#34](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/pull/34) (See [PR#22](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/pull/22) for more details), which allows one to use `--unit` command line option for `kernprof`, such as:

```
$ kernprof -l -v --unit 1e-3 myFile.py # milliseconds
```

```
$ kernprof -l -v --unit 1e-9 myFile.py # nanoseconds
```

etc.

Answer (score -2):

use "ms" to display:

edit `line_profiler.py`  ->  show_func  ->  find `for lineno, nhits, time in timings:`   this line  -> change `time` to `time * 10-03`

Comment: that's not a very convenient way to change the source code every time you want to change the time unit.